# How to change Kendo Scheduler week view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, scheduler

I want show days in week view on Kendo Scheduler in left column (not top).
I tried to search information about CustomView, but I couldn't find it.

Allow Kendo Scheduler make big changes in schedulr and how?

Answer (score 2):

Telerik has posted the custom view example project at http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view-329353883750. This should get you started in the customization you're looking for.

Comment: Sadly, the link doesn't point anywhere useful anymore :( I found similar-looking files at http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view-329353883750 and http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view-0286055de51d, not sure which one was meant originally.

Comment: I guess they updated the URL scheme on the forums. I've updated the link above. Sorry about that!

Comment: No problem, even knowing that there is a custom view example somewhere out there was of great help!